# Прочитать многомерный массив foreach

Tags: php

Вычитываю `JSON` ответ, в нем многомерный массив, делаю это так:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($this->arrayDepart['data']); $i++)
    {   
        echo "id - ".$i." ";
        echo "Address - ".$this->arrayDepart['data'][$i]['DescriptionRu']." ";
        echo "City - ".$this->arrayDepart['data'][$i]['CityDescriptionRu']." </br>";
    }
```

Мне почему-то это кажется говнокодом, как можно сделать тоже самое через `foreach` или это тоже нормально? `echo` - это для визуализации, на проде эта вычитка будет записываться в БД.

Comment: Можете использовать `foreach($this->arrayDepart['data'] AS $item_data)` и внутри цикла уже получать значения так `$item_data['DescriptionRu']`. В этом случае код будет компактнее и проще для восприятия.

Comment: @Pyramidhead не получается, там же есть еще `arrayDepart['data'][тут итератор]['DescriptionRu']`

Comment: выше все корректно написано, хз что у вас не получается. Если нужно значение индекса иметь то напишите `foreach(.... as $i => $item)`

Comment: @Pyramidhead, спасибо, ваш код сработал, я допустил ошибку.